# Get the mean frequency and mean amount of change of values in piecwise constant stepfunction/Timeseries - in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, correlation, frequency

I have data in a Timeseries that is piecewise constant. A value is always the valid value in this series until the next change occurs.

I want to detect the mean frequency of change in this series (i.e. how often are values changing), the mean month of year when this is happening and the mean absolute rate of change.

In a second step, I want to detect as well the mean of the negative change (i.e. the mean of values that are reduced) as well as the associated frequency and the associate month of year and the same for those values that are increasing (i.e. the mean of the positive change).

I have actually no clue how to start hence there is no MWE. I am currently trying to do autocorrellation on the differenced timeseries to get the times when a change occurs, but there has to be a simpler way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to ask something specific, even if you don't have any clue where to start. At minima, you should provide sample data in a friendly format and the matching expected output.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but you would find a python package staircase useful for this question www.staircase.dev